# Swipe controls for cross-platform Angular app

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, windows-phone-8.1

I am building a cross platform (Android, iOS, Windows) app using Angular 1.4.0, and would like to integrate swipe navigation on one of my app's views.

Initially I tried `ngTouch` and `ng-swipe-left`, `ng-swipe-right`, but these are not compatible with IE 11 on Windows Phone 8.1.

Is there any Angular support for Windows devices? Or perhaps another library? Or even better, a patch I can make for `ngTouch` to make it support IE11?